# Mysql Union returns duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got this query

```
(
SELECT u.Id, 1 AS which
FROM users u
JOIN user_opt uo ON u.id = uo.UserId
WHERE uo.country
IN (
'Spain',  'Azerbaijan'
)
AND uo.Hobbies REGEXP  'Astronomy'
LIMIT 100
)
UNION (

SELECT u.Id, 2 AS which
FROM users u
JOIN user_opt uo ON u.id = uo.UserId
WHERE uo.country
IN (
'Spain',  'Azerbaijan'
)
LIMIT 100
)
ORDER BY which
```

And because i use `UNION` in this query i should not get duplicate rows.But this returns duplicates rows.

Comment: `which` has different values on the two sides.  Edit your question or ask another question explaining what you really want to do.

Comment: It has different values so i can sort it @GordonLinoff

Comment: What exactkly do you want? 200 rows, 100 from each Select? Or exactly 100 rows possibly matching the regex and some additional rows if there are less than 100?

Comment: @dnoeth 200 rows

Comment: Then Gordon's answer is correct, and you can easily add `SELECT Id FROM (Gordon's Unions) AS dt ORDER BY which, Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to come pretty close to what you want by doing:

```
(SELECT u.Id, 1 AS which
 FROM users u JOIN
      user_opt uo
      ON u.id = uo.UserId
 WHERE uo.country IN ('Spain',  'Azerbaijan') AND
       uo.Hobbies REGEXP 'Astronomy'
 LIMIT 100
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT u.Id, 1 AS which
 FROM users u JOIN
      user_opt uo
      ON u.id = uo.UserId
 WHERE uo.country IN ('Spain',  'Azerbaijan') AND
       uo.Hobbies NOT REGEXP 'Astronomy'
 LIMIT 100
)
```

This is not *guaranteed* to put the first group first.  But in practice, it does.

Comment: But i want to get the result from first query first that's why i added `ORDER BY which`

Comment: @sakoaskoaso . . . In practice, this will do what you want.  It is not guaranteed to by the rules of SQL or by MySQL's documentation (as far as I know).  But it does because of the way that MySQL is implemented.  Note that this does not use `union`, but `union all`.

Comment: why did you choose union all? as far as i know union returns without duplicates

Comment: @sakoaskoaso . . . `UNION` should be avoided, if it can be replaced with `UNION ALL`.  The `WHERE` clause should prevent duplicates.